# SQL Who is being managed based on employee ID.

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Hello I have to write a query where I have to display:

- Manager's Number
- Manager's Full Name (combination of First, middle, and last columns)
- Employee Number
- Employee Full Name (again first, middle, and last)

And they all have to be for one specific manager, Dave. Dave's employee id is 100 if that helps.

So far I have

```
SELECT 
    EMP_MGR as "Manager's Number", 
    EMP_NUM as "Employee's Number", 
    EMP_FNAME || ' ' || EMP_INITIAL || '. ' || EMP_LNAME AS "Employee's Full Name", 

FROM EMP
    WHERE EMP_MGR = 108
```

I know I have to use a join somewhere, but I'm pretty lost on how to do it.

Comment: I bet this is not `SQL Server`, this is more on `SQLite` because of concatenation of fields. anyway, can you should the structure of your tale?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because user is already deleted and he/she haven't accepted any answers given and it's not even clear fo which RDBMS this answer should be

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
select
    M.EMP_NUM as "Manager's Number", 
    M.EMP_FNAME + ' ' + M.EMP_INITIAL + '. ' + M.EMP_LNAME AS "Manager's Full Name", 
    E.EMP_NUM as "Employee's Number", 
    E.EMP_FNAME + ' ' + E.EMP_INITIAL + '. ' + E.EMP_LNAME AS "Employee's Full Name"
from EMP as M
    inner join EMP as E on E.EMP_MGR = M.EMP_NUM 
where M.EMP_NUM = 100
```

Comment: 3535: A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.

Comment: Could you list your table definition? Are you sure you're working on SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    A.EMP_MGR as "Manager's Number", 
    B.EMP_NUM as "Employee's Number", 
    A.EMP_FNAME || ' ' || A.EMP_INITIAL || '. ' || A.EMP_LNAME AS "Manager's Full Name",
    B.EMP_FNAME || ' ' || B.EMP_INITIAL || '. ' || B.EMP_LNAME AS "Employee's Full Name", 

FROM EMP A
INNER JOIN EMP B ON A.EMP_NUM = B.EMP_MGR AND A.EMP_NUM = 108
```

Comment: Can you list the table definition.. this error means somewhere you're treating a string as a number. Can't tell where unless I know the types of your columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
    M.EMP_NUM as "Manager's Number", 
    M.EMP_FNAME + ' ' + M.EMP_INITIAL + '. ' + M.EMP_LNAME AS "Manager's Full Name", 
    E.EMP_NUM as "Employee's Number", 
    E.EMP_FNAME + ' ' + E.EMP_INITIAL + '. ' + E.EMP_LNAME AS "Employee's Full Name"
from EMP as M
    inner join EMP as E on E.EMP_MGR = M.EMP_NUM 
where M.EMP_NUM = '100'
```

The only difference is that I put the 100 in single quotes.  My guess is that the field called "EMP_NUM" is stored as a character string rather than a number.  If so, complain to the database designers for choosing a really bad name.  Won't help . . . but they might know.